# cURL leading to a 404 error

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-404

I'm facing a very surprising behaviour with a cURL request.
The script has been running fine for several months, but something happened and the code is not working any more.

```
$url = "http://domain.net:443/connexion.php";
$ch = curl_init();
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $f);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_errno($ch)){ 
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
    echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url']; 
} else { 
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); 
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the generated error:

- getaddrinfo(3) failed for domain.net:443
- Couldn't resolve host 'domain.net'
- Closing connection #0

So, it looks like a simple 404 error, but the point is that the requested url does exist, and is available from a browser...
I have no idea why the ressource is unavailable from cURL only.

Comment: When I try to open http://domain.net:443/connexion.php i can not open page either. Also 443 is for https so I tried https://domain.net/connexion.php but got 404 file not found. Is this domain.net your domain?

Comment: No it is not ; it is just to protect the website privacy. From a browser, http://domain.net does not work whereas http://domain.net:443 does.

Comment: check dns resolution on the server, e.g. pop up a shell and try `nslookup domain.net`. if that doesn't resolve, then there's your problem...

Comment: @Yako i can open domain.net but can not open domain.net:443.

Comment: and since that is not you domain how do you know that this script connexion.php is there now? I do not see problem in you curl!

Comment: @Marc I don't have any SSH access right now, so I can't test the availability of the ressource from the server's point of view. However, I copied the script on an other server, and it is working fine. Therefore, this is not a cURL related problem. So, what could make the server not seeing the targeted domain?

Comment: that's where you'd need a shell to go in and poke around. check resolver settings, check firewall settings (maybe dns-over-udp is working, but the response for that particular response is using tcp, which happens to be blocked), maybe the server's pointing at a dns server that's flakey, blah blah blah. tons of possbilities, but very few you can figure out remotely without shell access.